# VS Error: Octal escape sequences are only supported in ECMAScript 3 compatibility mode

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have twitter bootstrap setup to build in a new project, but am getting the following error from VS2010.

**Fatal error, cannot continue: Octal escape sequences are only supported in ECMAScript 3 compatibility mode.**

Which seems to be related to the following CSS/Less entry in bootstrap (type.less)...

```
blockquote small:before {
  content: '\2014 \00A0';
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to say that I had this error too, and the problem for me ended up being with Chirpy.  I tried to make a merged css file with it, but i was using .min files and i didn't use the chripy Minify="false" parameter in my File node.  Added that parameter and that fixed it right up