# Why does "\054321" produce ",321" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, grammar

Just tested in Chrome:

```
"\054321"
```

entered in the console gives:

```
",321"
```

Clearly `"\054"` gets converted to `","`, but I fail to find a rule for this in the [specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).

I am looking for a formal specification for this rule. **Why does `"\054"` produce `","`?**

**Update:** It was an `OctalEscapeSequence`, as defined in [B 1.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you will find that the octal value `054` (decimal: 44) is a comma.

You can find more on the [Values, variables, and literals - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings) page that specifies:

> ### Table 2.1 JavaScript special characters
>
> **Character**   **Meaning**
>   `XXX`           The character with the Latin-1 encoding specified by up to three octal digits `XXX` between `0` and `377`. For example, `\251` is the octal sequence for the copyright symbol.

So essentially, if you use an escape code of 3 digits, it will be evalutated as an octal value.

That said, be aware that octal escapes are [deprecated in ES5](http://es5.github.io/B.html#B.1) (*These have been removed from this edition of ECMAScript*) and you should use heximal or unicode escape codes instead (`\XX` or `\uXXXX`).

If you wish to have the literal string `\012345` then simply use a double backslash: `\\012345`.

Comment: Ah, [this](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.2) is what I missed in the specification.

Answer (score 2):

The Oct code for ***,*** is ***054***.

Check this [***Ascii Table***](http://www.asciitable.com/)

***Why you have to put "\" before that Oct code then??***

From a quick search you'll find lots of solutions. But this one gave me a better clearification.

***Octal escape sequences***

> *Any character with a character code lower than 256 (i.e. any character in the extended ASCII range) can be escaped using its octal-encoded character code, prefixed with . (Note that this is the same range of characters that can be escaped through hexadecimal escapes.)
>   To use the same example, the copyright symbol ('©') has character code 169, which gives 251 in octal notation, so you could write it as '\251'.*

[*The upper section was collected from an article which is* [***here***](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes)]

There are also some exceptions which you can find from that article.

Answer (score 0):

Because using \ in a string, as in other languages like C or Python, implies a special character, like \r as carriage return or \n as newline. In this case, It's the ascii value of the coma, which is 054.

Comment: The question was, where does the JavaScript specification define this escaping.

Comment: Not exactly where, but looks like it was introduced in EcmaScript 3. However, since version 5, it is considered deprecated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923987/vs-error-octal-escape-sequences-are-only-supported-in-ecmascript-3-compatibilit

Comment: Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856839/why-does-054321-produce-321-in-javascript/27856900?noredirect=1#comment44119345_27856898).

Answer (score 0):

"\054" is octal for ",". See here: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: The question was, where does the JavaScript specification define this escaping.